# Dynamically displaying picture from a folder in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have some cells with some values. This values are the names of a pictures in a folder. I would like to show the proper picture called "value" when I click a cell "value". I would like to do it dynamically, so that adding a picture causes displaying it when a cell with its name value is clicked. Could you tell me where should I start? Are there any tutorials showing how to do this? I found many, but they use lists and store pics in excel worksheet. Are there any examples?

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event and in that event you can launch the picture. BTW where are you planning to show the picture when the cell is clicked? In a comment? In a userform?

Comment: I would like to show it in a comment.

Comment: Ok I can give you the entire code but I would like you to try it first? Let's insert an image manually. Right click on the cell and click on `Show Comment`. Then right click on the borders of the comment and click on `Format Comment`. In the Format Box that appears select your image under `Color And Lines|Fill|Fill Effects`. Once you understand how an image is added simply record a macro and embed it in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`. Give it a try and if you are stuck then show the code that you tried and what error are you getting and we will take it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
           On Error Resume Next
          Dim imageFolder As String 'this is the folder where the image is located
    Dim imagePath As String


    Cells.Find("Code").Offset(1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
For Each cell In Selection
imageFolder = cell.Value
imagePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\kollol\My Documents\Quotes\Image\" & imageFolder

cell.Offset(0, 2).Select

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(imagePath & "\" & "1.jpeg").Select ' here the name of the image is 1.jpg


 With Selection
.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
 .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
.ShapeRange.Width = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
 .ShapeRange.Height = ActiveCell.RowHeight - 5
.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 10.5
.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 4#
 End With

Next cell

End Sub
```